# Zooming out breaks top navigation

Tags: css, zooming

When you zoom out on this site: https://www.zm-online.de/, it breaks the top nav on: PC: FF, Chrome, Safari (It's fine on IE9) on a MAC:Chrome and Safari (It's fine on FF).

I am thinking of fixing it on line number 598 and changing the padding from: 25 to 20, so the code will look like:

```
av#main_navi ul li a b.n2{
background: url("../_img/bg/mainnavi/bg_navi.jpg") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
color: #444;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
height: 37px;
line-height: 37px;
/*padding: 0 19px;*/
/*padding: 0 25px;*/
padding: 0 20px;
text-align: center;
```

}

However, this did NOT work on a PC and a MAC with Safari and Chrome and it made the top nav not look quite right in "normal" view. Any help would be appreciated. :-) Thanks!
Rita

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too specific to your site, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions have a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code *directly* into the question. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try setting your padding as a %.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to break the whole design. :(

Comment: Ok Have you tried adding float:none;overflow:hidden to the last <li> element?

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank your feedback. That does not seem to work either. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is not a good solution but if you change `font-size` to `10px` , the navigation doesn't break on Firefox.

And giving the `float` to the `li` makes some problems to me. I use `display:inline-block` for horizontal menu, `display:inline-block` is okay with IE,FF but Chrome has some bugs when your zoom level is 33% or 25%.

In my opinion try to design this nav with using `display:inline-block`.